# Localization of custom claim in Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have the following claim type in my relying party building block section:

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail">
    <DisplayName>Please select your preferred MFA method</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>RadioSingleSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Enumeration Text="Phone" Value="phone" SelectByDefault="true" />
      <!-- <Enumeration Text="Email " Value="email" SelectByDefault="false" /> -->
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

I'm not able to add the localization for another language, I have already set the trustframeworklocalization.xml file and it'w works for the other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved in part, I added on the selfasserted content definition id the following rows:

```
<!-- Self Asserted localized strings (English) -->
<LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.en">
<LocalizedStrings>
<LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" StringId="DisplayName">Please select your preferred MFA method</LocalizedString>
</LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, i added on the selfasserted content definition id the following rows:

```
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.en">
    <LocalizedCollections>
        <LocalizedCollection ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" TargetCollection="Restriction">
          <Item Text="Phone" Value="phone" />
          <Item Text="Email" Value="email" />
        </LocalizedCollection>
    </LocalizedCollections>  
    <LocalizedStrings>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" StringId="DisplayName">Please select your preferred MFA method</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
```